# spark with cassandra file system

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cluster-computing

I run Spark in Standalone mode ,Now I wanted to use data to process But I must Copy in all of the nodes in The same path.Now I decide to Use cassandra file system(CFS) to share data between all the nodes.
But how do I run my spark job to use cassandra keyspace/table data in another node?
How do I make Cassandra tables accessible by all the nodes?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve? Is it persisting data into cassandra database with spark jobs? Also, being a distributed database, cassandra by nature share data between all nodes based on the replication factor.

Comment: I have 3 cassandra nodes(machines),I want to reading data in spark with `sc.cassandraTable("kv", "tb")`  and now ,How do I set sparkconf?
`new SparkConf(true)
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "which node ip")`
Which cassandra Ip must be replaced?

Comment: Use all the three IPs separated by comma.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a comma separated list of initial contact points . The connector will read the metadata of cluster to find all the nodes in the cassandra cluster.

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.123.10,192.168.123.110")
```

refer for parameter details - [spark cassandra connector doc](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#cassandra-connection-parameters)